# How to setup Emacs to follow links in two ways depend on CTRL key

Tags: browser, emacs

Is there a way to change follow link in emacs to open it in w3m when click and in Chrome when click with CTRL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
(defun browse-url-with-w3m (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-browse-url))
    (browse-url-at-mouse event)))

(defun browse-url-with-default-browser (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-browser))
    (browse-url-at-mouse event)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'browse-url-with-w3m)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-down-mouse-1>") 'browse-url-with-default-browser)
```

Note that I assume that Chrome is your default browser and that you're
using emacs-w3m. Of course you can customize the variable
`browse-url-browser-function`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of **Daimrod**'s solution worked pretty well for me with three different browsers:

```
(defun browse-url-with-default-browser (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-browser))
       (mouse-set-point event)    
       (org-open-at-point)))

(defun browse-url-with-generic (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic))
       (mouse-set-point event)    
   (org-open-at-point)))

(defun browse-url-with-w3m (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-browse-url))
   (mouse-set-point event)    
   (org-open-at-point)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-1>") 'browse-url-with-default-browser)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-1>") 'browse-url-with-generic)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <mouse-1>") 'browse-url-with-w3m)

(custom-set-variables
  '(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-default-browser))
  '(browse-url-generic-program "chromium-browser"))
```

Though Firefox is not my default system browser Emacs somehow treats it as default. So, Firefox is launched with *mouse-1*, Chromium with *C-mouse-1* and w3m with *C-x mouse-1*